# saving particular location in bing maps for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I m developing an application in WP7 for storing the location which I have travelled through out the day. For example my current GPS location shows Newyork I would like to save that location to my phone and later on retrive the info from the stored database. How to save a location in Bing Maps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the [GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx) to get your current position and if needed the [CivicAddressResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.device.location.civicaddressresolver.aspx) to map coordinates to addresses.

Comment: Does CivicAddressResolver work at all. Its metioned in msdn site that its not implemented in current release

Comment: I wrote a program using it and it worked. Maybe the WP7 emulator doesn't support it.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether you tested it on a mango phone . It does not work on normal phones.

Comment: Is it possible to share your code so that I can test it on my phone

Comment: Yeah it's working with mango. Sorry but I can't share this code with you. I've no access on it from my current location... Maybe this Microsoft Location Service Sample helps you http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229128

Answer (score 0):

You could save the GeoCoordinate to Local Storage, or store it in a database. (Database is also stored in Local Storage) You can choose depending on your needs which solution you want to use. If you need to store multiple geocoordinates + maybe extra info I would suggest using the local database.

An example of how to use the [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) can be found in de the code samples section on MSDN.

When you return to your app, you can than bind the GeoCoordinates to the bing maps control by using [pushpins.](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/databinding-bingmaps-control-wp7-mvvm/)